# Which is more supported by web clients (browsers): SAN (Subject Alternative Name) or Wildcard SSL Certificates?

Tags: apache2, https, webserver, browsers

Which are more widely supported by browser clients, wildcard or SAN certificates?

I need to decide between using a SAN cert or a wildcard cert. Client/browser compatibility is my biggest concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Digicert maintains pages for compatibility with certificate types:

- [SAN certificate compatibility](http://digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm)
- [Wildcard certificate compatibility](http://digicert.com/ssl-support/wildcard-compatibility.htm)

They note several server side compatibility problems with wildcard certificates but no client side problems.  SAN certificates are problemic for some older browsers:

- Versions of major web browsers from before 2003.
- Older smart phones running Symbian OS
- Older Palm Treo

If supporting these older browsers is important to you, then wildcard certificates have wider browser support.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! An excellent answer and getting a compatibility listing for both from the same source is a good way to make a comparison. I had trouble finding such a thing so I am very glad to see that Digicert provides compatibility information for both.

Comment: Does Chrome really lack SAN support in September 2016?  I am missing it on Digicert's compatibility page referenced in this answer.

Comment: Chrome supports SAN just fine and has for years.     All major web browsers have supported SAN since about 2003.